# Get nested property of json varibale in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

How to take all property of a json variable in node js and put all of them in a txt file?
If the structure of the JSON is like below, I could create a txt file of the property only.

```
// JSON Variable
const jsonValue1 = {
    "prop1": "val1",
    "prop2": "val2",
    "prop3": "val3",
}

const fs = require('fs')
const keys = Object.keys(jsonValue1)
const fileName = './keys_id.txt'
fs.writeFileSync(fileName, keys.join('\n))
```

// Output in the keys_id.txt file

```
prop1
prop2
prop3
```

But, what if the structure of my JSON is like this:

```
const jsonValue2 = {
    "prop1": "val1",
    "prop2": {
        "prop2_1": "val2_1"
        "prop2_2": "val2_2"
    }
    "prop3": "val3"
}
```

How to get the nested property? Actually, my expected output in the file would be like this:

```
prop1
prop2.prop2_1
prop2.prop2_2
prop3
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a recursive `reduce` over the `entries` of the input object:

```js
const inputObj = {
  "prop1": "val1",
  "prop2": {
    "prop2_1": "val2_1",
    "prop2_2": "val2_2"
  },
  "prop3": "val3"
};
const getKeys = (obj, props=[], accum=[]) => (
  Object.entries(obj).reduce((a, [key, val]) => {
    const thisPropArr = [...props, key];
    if (typeof val === 'object') {
      a.push(...getKeys(val, thisPropArr))
    } else {
      a.push(thisPropArr.join('.'));
    }
    return a;
  }, accum)
);
console.log(getKeys(inputObj));
```

Note that you need to correct the syntax for your `jsonValue2` object - key-value pairs need to be separated by *commas*. (pairs separated by spaces alone will result in a `SyntaxError`)

Also note that what you have is just a *plain object*, not a JSON - JSON is a *method of representing an object in string format*. If serialization / deserialization is not involved, then JSON is not involved either. Probably better to name your input object something like `inputObj` rather than `jsonValue#`, to keep from confusing yourself.